# Show different Google analytics javascripts based on url parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display different Google analytics codes based on a URL parameter

I have different affiliate IDs attached in the url and these affiliate IDs get carried across the site as users browser through. Whats the best way to show different scripts based on ID?

**Sample Affiliate id**

http://www.website.com.au/?afid=AFF1

http://www.website.com.au/?afid=AFF2

**This is what I have right now**

```
var CurrentUrl = window.location.href;
var SplitUrl = CurrentUrl.split('afid=')[1];

if (SplitUrl === 'AFF1') {  
 //show GA code one

}

else if (SplitUrl === 'AFF2') {
  //show GA code two
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dynamically create the ga tracker:

ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'auto');
(https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced)

You just have to include the GA js before that point.